# Use graphics2d object outside paintComponent method?

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d, java-2d

**My code:**

```
public class YesOrNo{

    Graphics g;

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        JPanel x=new JPanel(){
        @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            }
        }
    }

    public void drawARectangle(){
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

I know I can call a method inside paintComponent and pass `g` to it as parameter, but can you do it without calling that method inside `paintComponent`?

Comment: *"but can you do it without calling that method inside paintComponent?"* If the `Graphics` is from a `BufferedImage`, then the answer is "yes, sure".  If the `Graphics` is supplied by the toolkit, then, "no".

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  All drawing takes place in the paintComponent method, or a method called by the paintComponent method.  Now, calculating the objects you want to draw should happen elsewhere in your code.